# How to get the AJAX result in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When the result exists it's not going to the `if` condition, it will go to `else`. In query result `$num>0` I want an alert like "receipt number already exists".

```
$.post("acceptajax.php?confirm1="+confirm+'&receipt='+receipt+'&amount='+amount,function(result,status){
    //$('#divsub'+confirm).html(data);
    if(result == 'exist'){
        alert('Receipt number Alerady Exit');
    } else {
        $('#accept_'+confirm).hide();
        $('#unaccept_' +confirm).show();
    }
});
```

`acceptajax.php`:

```
$img_id=$_GET['confirm1'];
$receipt=$_GET['receipt'];
$receipt='HYD'.$receipt;
$amount=$_GET['amount'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT receipt FROM user WHERE receipt=$receipt");
$num=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($num==0){
    echo "suc";
} else {
    echo "exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `'` around `$receipt`. Try this :

```
"SELECT receipt FROM user WHERE receipt='$receipt'"
```

> Side note :
>
> 1) Please dont use `mysql_`. It is deprecated and removed
>   from PHP 7.Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
>
> 2) Your query is open for sql injection. Read this :
>   [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

use query like this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT receipt FROM user WHERE receipt='".$receipt."'");
```

and instead of using this because this is not right way to code, because you are using post method to send data and sending it using get method.

```
$.post("acceptajax.php?confirm1="+confirm+'&receipt='+receipt+'&amount='+amount,function(result,status)
```

you should use it like this:

```
$.post("acceptajax.php", {confirm1:confirm, receipt: receipt, amount: amount}, function(result, status){
   //your script
 });
```

and get the data on acceptajax.php using $_POST[]; method. Hope it Helps.